# serve angular app using angular-cli

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

I have created an Angular 2 app using angular-cli, but when I try to serve this application using ng-serve I am facing following error:

```
 vendor.bundle.js net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH
bootstrap 195fcde…:54 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 195fcde…:54)
    at Object.2 (main.ts:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 195fcde…:54)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap 195fcde…:25)
    at main.bundle.js:1
```

I did notice vendor.bundle.js is too large: that's the reason it can't be loaded in the browser. So, how can I optimize in develop environment? 
N. B.: I have not changed any line of code of my application, it is a fresh install hello-world application.

Comment: what is your version of cli ?

Comment: angular cli 1.2.0

Comment: can you clear browsers cache and try just a guess not sure if it a fresh project why this error

Comment: Can you add your package.json here please?

Answer (score 0):

Use latest version of angular cli. This issue is fixed already.

Please read following link for details

https://github.com/civetweb/civetweb/issues/422